# ADF publish fails looking for a managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-managed-identity

Attempting to publish in Data Factory but it fails as it cannot find a managed identity. This "Test-user-managed-identity" user managed identity I had created in my sandbox resource group while testing a separate solution and should not used anywhere within our dev ADF code. I checked all of our linked services and all use System Assigned Managed Identity. Can anyone help me to possibly locate where this identity is being used/referenced?

[image: Error:]

Comment: does it show on the Managed Identities page in Azure portal for ADF (not in the authoring studio)?

Comment: Yes! There it is under the User Assigned identities. Thank you, Scott! Please make that an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look under the Managed Identities page in Azure portal for the ADF (not in the authoring studio).

[image]